# Display dates from MS Access table using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I had a DataGridView and i want to display the dates from a specific time. Heres my code.

```
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    con.Open()
                End If

                Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblListDates WHERE reserveDate >=#" & CDate(lblFrom.Text) & "# or reserveDate <=#" & CDate(lblTo.Text) & "# ORDER BY ID", con)
                Dim Dt As New DataTable
                rs.Fill(Dt)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = Dt
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    con.Close()
                End If
```

Assuming that that my label (lblFrom.text = Sunday, 12 October 2014 01:00 AM) and
label(lblTo.text = Monday, 13 October 2014 01:30 AM) . But the Date(Monday, 13 October 2014 10:30 AM) was displayed even though its not included in my range dates. Is there something wrong with my code? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, why would you be taking values from `Labels`?  `Labels` are for displaying data to the user and that's all.  They are not for data storage.  Where did the dates in the `Labels` come from?  That's the data you should be using.  you should have `Date` variables to store that data and takle it from there when you want to use it.  You should also be using parameters to insert those values into your SQL code.

Comment: As for the issue, do you know the difference between AND and OR?  They mean exactly the same thing in SQL code as they mean in day-to-day life.  If I said that I wanted the names of everyone who is older than 20 or younger than 30, is that going to include someone who's 10?  Of course it is.  In fact, it's going to include absolutely everybody.  If I say older than 20 and younger than 30, that's something altogether different, isn't it?

Comment: i have to datetimepicker first for the day and second for the hours and minute. So to combine the value of datetimepicker's i used label. Okay thanks for now i got some idea from you. Ill try it later. BTW thanks.